# Getting the values from a JSON

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

each entry in the JSON, looks like this:

```
{
  "ALBA": [
    {
      "name": "ABRUD",
      "zip": "515100",
      "lat": "46.274675",
      "long": "23.065029"
    },
    {
      "name": "ABRUD-SAT",
      "zip": "515101",
      "lat": "46.283967",
      "long": "23.061093"
    },
}
```

The first object is the county name, I have more of them, but I just gave an example, the nested objects are the cities. What I want is a way to display them in a select tag in HTML, but I can't manage to do it.

I have the following code, until now:

```
const getCities = () => {
    // Object.keys(regions).map(function(key, index) {
    //   console.log(regions[key]);
    // })
    for (const region in regions) {
      console.log(region); //this returns exactly what i want
    //cities.push(region)
    }
  }
  getCities();
```

And in html:

```
<div>
            <select name="city">
              <option value={cities}>{cities}</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

How can I make this select tag return me exactly the counties and how to make another one to show me the cities name based on the selected county?

EDIT:
I managed to do it doing the following:

```
const getCities = () => {
    for (const region in regions) {
      cities.push(region);
    }
    return cities
  }
  getCities();


<div>
        <label htmlFor="city">County</label>
        <select name="city"
        onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
        >
          {cities.map((city) => {
            return (
              <option value={city} key={city}>{city}</option>
            )
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question (only in that millisecond you pass the return value of `JSON.stringify()` to `JSON.parse()` in that no-op in the first line of `getCities()`)

Comment: What's the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(regions))` this converts `region` to a string (JSON) and then parses it again immediately after. The result of that is not assigned anywhere, so there's no point to this line at all, it's just wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: _"console.log(region); //this returns exactly what i want"_ - Why? That's a region (`ALBA`) o.O The function is named `getCities()`. the name of the `<select>` is `city`...

Comment: You are right, I deleted the first line.

Comment: What is the regions variable? 
The whole code will be helpful.

Comment: regions is the json, that is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following....

```js
const countryCityMap = {
  "ALBA": [{
      "name": "ABRUD",
      "zip": "515100",
      "lat": "46.274675",
      "long": "23.065029"
    },
    {
      "name": "ABRUD-SAT",
      "zip": "515101",
      "lat": "46.283967",
      "long": "23.061093"
    }
  ]
}

function bindCountryCity(countryCityMap) {
  const countrySelector = document.querySelector('#countrySelector');

  const citySelector = document.querySelector('#citySelector');

  if (countrySelector) {
    clearOptions(countrySelector);
    addDefault(countrySelector);

    // Populate Countries
    Object.keys(countryCityMap).forEach(country => addOption(countrySelector, country, country));

    countrySelector.onchange = countrySelected
  }

  if (citySelector) {
    citySelector.onchange = function(selector) {
      console.log('[City Selection Changed]', selector.target.value);
    }
  }

  function addDefault(selector) {

    if (selector) {
      const defaultValue = selector.getAttribute('data-default-value') || 'select';
      const defaultText = selector.getAttribute('data-default-text') || 'select';
      addOption(selector, defaultText, defaultValue);
    }
  }


  function addOption(selector, optionText, optionValue) {
    if (selector) {
      selector.add(new Option(optionText, optionValue));
    }
  }


  function clearOptions(selector) {

    if (selector) {
      while (selector.options.length) {
        selector.remove(0);
      }
    }
  }

  function countrySelected(selectionChanged) {
    const selectedCountry = selectionChanged.target.value;
    console.log('[Country Selection Changed]', selectedCountry);

    clearOptions(citySelector);
    addDefault(citySelector);
    if (countryCityMap[selectedCountry]) {
      // populate corresponding cities
      countryCityMap[selectedCountry].map(cityEntry => getCityNames(cityEntry)).filter(x => (x || '').trim()).forEach(city => addOption(citySelector, city, city));
    }

    function getCityNames(cityEntry) {
      if (cityEntry && (cityEntry.name || '').trim()) {
        return (cityEntry.name || '').trim();
      }
    }
  }
}

bindCountryCity(countryCityMap);
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="countrySelector" data-default-value="select_a_country" data-default-text="Select a country" style="margin: 10px; float: left">
    <option value="select_a_country">Select a country</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select id="citySelector" data-default-value="select_a_city" data-default-text="Select a city" style="margin: 10px">
    <option value="select_a_city">Select a city</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was about rendering elements from a nested data structure with **react**.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, now that you have mentioned, I just saw. Also, the OP has been edited later to reflect the `react`-ishness.